# Capistrano - method_missing map

Tags: ruby, capistrano

My deploy script throw error. I use capistrano and gem `railsless-deploy`

Error:
`` /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:193:in `method_missing': undefined method `map' for #<Capistrano::Configuration::Namespaces::Namespace:0x00000001a634b0> (NoMethodError) ``

My Capfile

```rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'railsless-deploy'
# load 'deploy'

load 'app/config/deploy'
```

My deploy.rb

```rb
#...more code...#
set :myfiles, ["path/to/file.ext","path/to/another/file.ext"]
#...more code...#
namespace :myfiles do
    task :check do
        myfiles.map do |file|
            #...more code...#
        end
    end
end
```

`ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]`

`cap  -V
Capistrano v2.15.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a variable `myfiles` and then the scope a few lines later overrides that. That's why capistrano tries to send the `map` method to the namespace and fails. Change the list's name to something else like:

```
set :file_list, ["path/to/file.ext","path/to/another/file.ext"]
#...more code...#
namespace :myfiles do
    task :check do
        file_list.map do |file|
            #...more code...#
        end
    end
end
```